# Working with relative paths in webpack 2 / jQuery theme

Tags: jquery, canvas, webpack

Working with my first webpack set up and can't quite seem to resolve this issue.

On the main app.js entry point, the path for a specific folder (jsFileLocation variable) is not finding the folder in the public directory:

```
var tpj=jQuery;
tpj(document).ready(function() {
    var apiRevoSlider = tpj('.tp-banner').show().revolution({
         sliderType:"standard",
         jsFileLocation: "./assets/canvas/rs-plugin/include/js",
         sliderLayout:"fullscreen",
...
```

On the public directory we have:

```
── assets
│   ├── canvas
│   │   └── includes
│   │   │   └── rs-plugin
│   │   │   │   └── js
```

All other imports on the app.js file work without a problem. This results in a broken jQuery slider as seen here:

- https://cloudup.com/cHSIyOEgVFS

and the console error:

- https://cloudup.com/cnak33E4ulM

and the sources panel, which does not show the /includes folder:

- https://cloudup.com/c7FTkN-Odfh

What am I missing? I tried various combinations of paths for the jsFileLocation variation without avail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Webpack. Webpack will bundle your imported files. Check the docs [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/)

The `"./assets/canvas/rs-plugin/include/js"` will not be handled by Webpack. This code will be executed when the document is ready in the browser. Put it in a folder that can be accessed via http and it should be loaded correctly.

Regarding the `TweenLite` error: It seems that you are using 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/gsap'. So install that via `npm` to have it available for webpack to resolve.